# Override mouse wheel behavior in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, vb.net, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm creating a Windows Store App (Metro) for Windows 8.1 and I have a `ScrollViewer` control hosting images and other controls. The default behavior of the mouse wheel is to scroll, and if coupled with the CTRL button to zoom. I would like to change that behavior so that it zooms without the need for the CTRL button. Unfortunately, since Windows 8.1 the `PointerWheelChanged` event no longer fires and since it is a sealed class I cannot subclass it.

Is there any way to implement my own behavior for the mouse wheel other than downgrading to Windows 8?

Comment: Changing the default contextual behavior of a human-computer interface  is usually a very bad idea, unless it produces a behavior that is consistent with previous versions of your application (and is thus expected).

Comment: @BrianDriscoll - That's exactly why I want to try to do this. Our users expect the mouse wheel to change zoom.

Comment: Yeah, in mapping and other applications, scrolling would be far more unusual than a zoom.

Comment: Quote from MSDN: "For Windows 8, track pad device gestures that were input-handled by a ScrollViewer control part were interpreted as mouse wheel input, and thus would fire a PointerWheelChanged event. Starting with Windows 8.1, ScrollViewer uses an underlying manipulation logic that interprets track pad gestures as actions that the ScrollViewer responds to, and thus the gesture is considered handled by the control and the PointerWheelChanged event is not fired anymore."

Comment: @HansPassant, I wonder if that means he just needs to listen to `OnManipulationStarted` and filter for scroll manipulations.